# Comparar dos objetos PHP

Tags: php, array, comparaciones

Tengo un problema, actualmente trato de comparar dos objetos un objeto es ventas en efectivo y el otro es ventas con tarjeta.

> Ventas en efectivo

```
[
  {
    "ventas": 1,
    "dia": 7,
    "total": 120
  },
  {
    "ventas": 1,
    "dia": 8,
    "total": 100
  }
]
```

> Ventas con tarjeta

```
[
  {
    "ventas": 3,
    "dia": 8,
    "total": 360
  }
]
```

Pero para los reportes diarios usando ChartJs trato de obtener esta estructura:

> Ventas en efectivo

```
[1, 1]
```

> Ventas con tarjeta

```
[0, 3]
```

Para eso trato de realizar con un `foreach`

```
foreach ($ventasEfectivo as $keyEfecitvo => $efectivo) {
       $contado[] = $efectivo->ventas;
       foreach ($ventasTarjeta as $keyCredito => $credito) {
           if ($keyEfecitvo == $keyCredito) {
               $credito[] = $credito->ventas;
           }elseif(isset($keyCredito)){
               $credito[] = 0;
           }
       }
}
```

Pero esto me retorna:

```
[3,0]
```

En lugar de

```
[0, 3]
```

Answer (score 2):

Creo que esto podría ayudar. Usamos una variable autoincremental para comparar el día y poder sacar el array completo con todos los días:

```
function count_ventas($ventasEfectivo, $ventasTarjeta, $cantidad){
    for($i = 1; $i <= $cantidad; $i++){
        foreach($ventasEfectivo as $venta){
            if($i == $venta['dia']){
                $ventas['contado'][$i] = $venta['ventas'];
            }
            if(!isset($ventas['contado'][$i])){
                $ventas['contado'][$i] = 0;
            }
        }
        foreach($ventasTarjeta as $keyCredito => $credito){
            if ($i == $credito['dia']){
                $ventas['creditos'][$i] = $credito['ventas'];
            }
            if(!isset($ventas['creditos'][$i])){
                $ventas['creditos'][$i] = 0;
            }
        }
    }
    return $ventas;
}

print_r(count_ventas($ventasEfectivo, $ventasTarjeta, 8));
//Array ( [contado] => Array ( [1] => 0 [2] => 0 [3] => 0 [4] => 0 [5] => 0 [6] => 0 [7] => 1 [8] => 3 ) [creditos] => Array ( [1] => 0 [2] => 0 [3] => 0 [4] => 0 [5] => 0 [6] => 0 [7] => 0 [8] => 3 ) )
```

No pude chequear el funcionamiento porque estoy desde el teléfono, pero creo que la lógica está correcta.

Saludos!

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta, pero el algoritmo solo toma en cuenta el ultimo día de los objetos, si digamos tengo una venta con tarjeta el dia 7 no lo toma.

Comment: Ya lo actualicé @CarlosMendez, ya recibe bien los datos.